# How can i left align an image with text heading above it and text below it

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-4

How can I get the image in the below html to align left so it matches the left edge of the heading text  and the left edge of the text below it? When I run this the image is indented by a few pixels which does not let it look like it is left aligned with the heading or the text below it. The image is only 128 pixels wide. Thanks in advance.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>
                <h3>Technical Diagrams</h3><br />
                <a class="nav-link" href="~/Graphics/TechnicalDiagrams">
                    <img  class=".img-fluid" border="0" alt="Technical Design Documents" src="~/Content/Images/Technical/An N-Tier Architecture Example Using Visual Studio (2016-01-12)(370Thumb).jpg">
                </a><br />
                This is a collection of images which were used in the past to communicate process or software workflows and architecture.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `~` in your link refs? Outside of the shell, that makes no sense.

Comment: We cannot reproduce this error in your question's current state. Please upload the images, use snippets, etc., so that we can *see* what you're describing.

Comment: Remove the period from "img-fluid".
probably "nav-link" or ".img-fluid" classes have some padding or margin.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution would be to add one of the padding classes to the hyperlink, for example "p-0" to remove padding entirely. You should remove dot from class "img-fluid" for your image. Also your HTML code violates list of allowed elements in paragraph, search "Phrasing content".

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add padding and margin settings of zero to the div container surrounding the img tag.  Also to remove the period in front of the .img-fluid class name.  This is a snippet from an ASP.NET MVC 5 page using Bootstrap. The tilde symbol is used in this type of page under visual studio to reference the root directory.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p>
            <h3>Technical Diagrams</h3><br />
            <a class="nav-link" style="padding:0; margin:0;" href="~/Graphics/TechnicalDiagrams">
                <img  class="img-fluid" border="0" alt="Technical Design Documents" src="~/Content/Images/Technical/An N-Tier Architecture Example Using Visual Studio (2016-01-12)(370Thumb).jpg">
            </a><br />
            This is a collection of images which were used in the past to communicate process or software workflows and architecture.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```